# Rich notification on iOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications, rich-notifications

I need to enable Rich notification on iOS 10 and above for iPhone (5x,6x & 7x) models. The notifications come with an embedded image and the image should be expanded by default. See the sample image below:

[image: Full view width utilized.]

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I have created an example in documentation for Rich Notification in iOS 10 have a look at it u may get some ideas about Rich Notification , The example is about displaying images in `UNNotificationContentExtension`

**Step 1**

Making the environment suitable for Notification. Make sure you enabled **Background Modes** and **Push Notification** [image: Enabling Background Modes]

[image: Enabling Push Notifications]

**Step 2: Creating an UNNotificationContentExtension**

Click on the **+** icon in the bottom which creates a target template and select Notification Content Extention -> next -> create a name for the content extension -> finish [image: Creating UNNotificationContentExtension]

**Step 3:Configuring the info.plist file of the created extension**

[image]

The dictionary in NSExtension signifies how the notification content is displayed, these are performed on long pressing the received notification

- UNNotificationExtensionOverridesDefaultTitle: We can give custom title for our notification by default it displays the name of the application `self.title = myTitle`
- UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden: This boolean determines whether the default body of the notification is to be hidden or not
- UNNotificationCategory: Category is created in `UNUserNotificationCenter` in your application. Here it can be either a string or an array of strings, so each category can gave different types of data from which we can create different UI's. The payload we send must contain the category name in order to display this particular extension
- UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio: The size of the initial content ie when displaying the ContentExtension for the first time the initial size with respect to width of the device. here 1 denotes the height will be equal to the width

**Step 4: Creating `UNNotificationAction` and `UNNotificationCategory` in our application**

In your app's AppDelegate.swift `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function add

```
    let userNotificationAction:UNNotificationAction = UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "ID1", title: "வணக்கம்", options: .destructive)
    let userNotificationAction2:UNNotificationAction = UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "ID2", title: "Success", options: .destructive)

    let notifCategory:UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory.init(identifier: "CATID1", actions: [userNotificationAction,userNotificationAction2], intentIdentifiers: ["ID1","ID2"] , options:.customDismissAction)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([notifCategory])
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

We created two `UNNotificationAction` with identifiers `ID1` and `ID2` and added those actions to a `UNNotificationCategory` with identifier `CATID1` (the categoryID in ContentExtension's info.plist file are same, what we created here should be used in payload and the plist file). We set the category to our application's `UNUserNotificationCenter` and in next line we are registering for the notification which calls the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function where we get the device token

Note: dont forget to `import UserNotifications` in your AppDelegate.swift and add `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

**Step 5: Sample payload for the NotificationContent**

```
 'aps': {
    'badge': 0,
    'alert': {
        'title': "Rich Notification",
        'body': "Body of RICH NOTIFICATION",
        },
    'sound' : "default",
    'category': "CATID1",
    'mutable-content':"1",
    },
'attachment': "2"
```

**Step 6: Configuring the ContentExtension**

The corresponding actions for the category is automatically displayed while the notification action is performed. Lets us see the code how its being performed

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
     self.title = "Koushik"
    imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "welcome.jpeg")
}

func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {

    self.title = "Koushik"
    imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "Success.jpeg")

    if(response.actionIdentifier == "ID1")
    {
       imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "Success.jpeg")
    }
    else
    {
        imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "welcome.jpeg")
    }

    }
}
```

**Step 7: Result**

After receiving and long press/Clicking View notification, the notification looks like this [image]

The title is "Koushik" since we gave `self.title = "Koushik"` and `UNNotificationExtensionOverrideDefaultTitle` as YES. In step 3 we gave `UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden` as NO if its YES then the notification will look like images 3 and 4.

**Note:** We cannot use scroll view or anykind of scrolls in content Extension but we can use `self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: minimumSize.height)` to increase the content size of the view But the default Messages app uses scrolling. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: is this work in application background and killed state?

Comment: Yeah, It works in both state.